# Not a valid win32 application error while running Cordova App in visual studio 2015

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

While I am trying to run my Cordova application in Visual Studio 2015 using Ripple- Nexus(Galaxy)[image]

I am getting the error, 'node.exe is not a valid Win32 application' in the following manner multiple times:

[image]

After canceling the message box for a couple of times I get the following error list:

[image]

> Severity  Code    Description File    Line    Source  Suppression State
>
> Error     '"C:\Users\abcd\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\vs-npm\2.14.9"\nodevars.bat'
> is not recognized as an internal or external command, C:\Program Files
> (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets  285 Build
>
> Error     operable program or batch file. C:\Program Files
> (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets  285 Build
>
> Error     Access is denied.   C:\Program Files
> (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets  285 Build
>
> Error     Error installing local npm package. C:\Program Files
> (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets  285 Build
>
> Error MSB6003 The specified task executable "app.js" could not be run.
> The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS
> platform. C:\Program Files
> (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets  317 Build

Can somebody please guide to resolve the same and make the app run.

Comment: Have you tried to install the 32bit version of node.js?

Comment: @Frix33 yes, I tried it with 32bit as well.

Comment: Have you checked if the path in your error message points to your node installation / your node.exe?

Comment: @Phonolog Yes, it is pointing towards the correct path

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you downloaded a corrupted version of Node during install. Delete the folder "vs-npm" in %appdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\vs-npm, and try building again.